# Create multi-colored polygon without external libraries or sprites

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to create a 9 x 9 rectangle and I want to make the color arrangement of the rectangle to vary. Right now I'm using fillStyle('#0000FF') to fill it with blue, but I'd like to fill it with a random arrangement of colors. Is that possible?

Comment: Exactly how would you want the canvas to be filled fo reach random color? Entire canvas, portion of the canvas (square, circle, etc), ... ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function to generate a semi-random color:

```
function randomColor(){ 
    return('#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));
}
```

You can do `context.fillStyle=randomColor()` and `context.fillRect(...)` for each of your 9x9 sub-rectangles inside your big rectangle.

Here's a fancier example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

ctx.lineWidth=10;
var nextTime=0;
var duration=1000;

requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function animate(time){
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  if(time>nextTime){
    nextTime=time+duration;
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    for(var i=0;i<cw*2;i+=ctx.lineWidth){
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(i,-5);
      ctx.lineTo(i-cw,ch+5);
      ctx.strokeStyle=randomColor();
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  }
}

function randomColor(){ 
  return('#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

[image]

**[ More to the questioners point :-) ]**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
var colwidth=cw/9;
var rowheight=ch/9;

for(var y=0;y<9;y++){
for(var x=0;x<9;x++){
    ctx.fillStyle=randomColor();
    ctx.fillRect(x*colwidth,y*rowheight,colwidth,rowheight);
}}

function randomColor(){ 
  return('#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: I meant more in the sense that the rectangle itself is filled with multiple random colors

Answer (score 1):

To get random colors the best way is to use the hsl system (hue, saturation, lightness).
This way you can easily 'shape the randomness' of the colors.

The code below selects randomly one of 3 color scheme and draws the rectangles using this scheme.
Use an hsl color wheel to find out which colors would be fit.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var colorScheme = -1;

function drawRect() {
  colorScheme = randInt(3);

  ctx.save();
  ctx.scale(30,30);
  var i=9,j;
  while(i--) {
     j=9;
     while(j--) {
       ctx.fillStyle=randomColor();
       ctx.fillRect(i,j,1, 1);
     }
  }
  ctx.restore();
}

drawRect();
setInterval(drawRect, 1400);
function randomColor(){ 
  var hue, saturation, lightness;
  // 8 bit : 6 very contrasted colors
  if (colorScheme == 0) {
     hue = 60*randInt(6);
     saturation = 85;
     lightness = 50;
  } 
  // random hue, normal sat/lgt
  if (colorScheme == 1) {
     hue = randInt(360);
     saturation = 80;
     lightness = 65;
  } 
  // red theme : all colors in 0-30, lightness in 65-100
  if (colorScheme == 2) {
     hue = randInt(30);
     saturation = 70;
     lightness = 65+randInt(36);
  } 
  
  return 'hsl(' + hue + ',' + saturation +  '%,' +lightness + '%)';
}

function randInt(max) {
   return Math.floor(Math.random()*max);  
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```